# ExtJS composite fields

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Let me explain my situation:

I have model with array field inside it

```
Ext.define('MyModel',{
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: [
    { name: 'myfield', type: 'array' }
  ]
})
```

that contents data like this

```
data = Ext.create('MyModel',{
  myfield: [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ]
})
```

I want to extend `Ext.form.field.Base` to create field that treats this array as todo-list and contains items inside itself ( `Ext.form.field.Trigger` to add "todo" and `Ext.ListView` to display "todo's" ).

I don't know how difficult it is to make `Ext.form.field.Base` contain items and are there any better possible solutions.

Field must get array on `loadRecord()` and give it on `getRecord()` of Form.

Other possible solutions I see:

1) Make Field only with html-template and vanilla-javascript ( bad because why to implement things that are already present in ExtJS )

2) Model relations ( bad because I have to implement 'create, update and delete' for each related model and load them manually )

Thank you for reading, any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not related directly to your question, but "array" is not a valid field type for a Ext.data.Field. Use 'auto' for no data conversion, or just don't assign a type.

Re: the custom, complex form field, it's certainly possible with ExtJS, and creating an extension of the Trigger field is definitely what you'll want to do. Here's an example of a custom trigger field that handles complex data: http://existdissolve.com/2012/12/extjs-4-custom-editor-for-property-grid/. The example is for a custom property grid, but the principle is the same for any custom form field.

The most important parts in your custom field are going to be the implementation of the [createPicker()](http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker-method-createPicker) method and whatever mechanism you define for setting the value of the underlying field.

Hope this gives you a good place to start.